# Yet another 'column _id does not exist' issue

Tags: android, database, cursor, adaptor

I think I have checked all the previous posts on this issue but none seem to be helping me...

Basic stuff - trying to use a cursor adaptor bound to my database but I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

My schema has that column defined (although I do have 2 tables, both with the same name - is that an issue?), like this:

```
public static abstract class dbMain implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mpgMain";
    public static final String ENTRY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String VEHICLE_NAME = "v_name";

}

public static abstract class dbHistory implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mpgHistory";
    public static final String ENTRY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String TRIP_DATE = "date";

}
```

From other posts, I have put _id in my cursor porjection:

```
String[] projection = {dbMain.ENTRY_ID, dbMain.VEHICLE_NAME};

Cursor mpgCur = mpgDB.query(dbMain.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
```

...but then my stack trace gives the same error, on the query line. If I remove the ENTRY_ID from the projection, the same error but on the later line instantiating the adaptor:

```
String[] fromColumns = {dbMain.VEHICLE_NAME};
int[] toViews = {R.id.displayVehicle};

SimpleCursorAdapter vehAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    R.layout.activity_first_screen, mpgCur, fromColumns, toViews, 0);  <--- HERE
```

I've also tried putting a space in the CREATE TABLE command, before the _id field:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_MAIN_TABLE =
"CREATE TABLE " + dbMain.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
    dbMain.ENTRY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
```

Any ideas gratefully received...

Comment: did. you try to Log.d all the cursor column names?

Comment: `on the query line.` that means the table does not contain a column _id. You probably have added it after the creation of the table, and not updated your table meanwhile. uninstalling and reinstalling the application should solve it.

Comment: Does that count if I'm only working on the emulator and rebuikding every time?

Comment: njzk2 - many thanks, you were right! I didn't realise the emulator was so literal and actually had 'installed' the app - I thought every time I hit 'Run' in Eclipse, I was effectively re-installing - obviously not. Uninstalled and all fine - many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, by implementing BaseColumns, you don't have to specify "_id" in your schema. Just use the constant _ID (so, `dbMain._ID` and `dbHistory._ID`)

Comment: true, but irrelevant to the question. Implementing BaseColumns only provides you with constants. The use of said constants is up to you.

Comment: Very true. What you commented on the main post makes sense. Didn't even think of that.